# ChangeCursor() everytime after adding data to SQLlite DB seems rather wastul and inefficient

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-cursoradapter, qsqlquery

As part of learning some Android programming, I was given the task to write a simple todo application, which stores tasks on the SQLlite DB.

I use a cursorAdapter (or a custom extension of this class) in order to 'link' to a listView within the xml, cotaining the actual tasks the user adds.

My application should support two simple opperations on this list: Add and Remove. The thing is that everytime I add or Remove an item (task) from this list, the current adapter has a cursor which is no longer relevant, so I have to replace it (adapter.chagneCursor(newCursor) ) with another one.

The flow is something like this:

1. Add task requested
2. Execute a SQL query (table insert etc.)
3. Update the adapter's cursor: adapter.changeCursor( newCursor )

   - The problem I have is with this newCursor - this newCursor is achieved by running another method which executes an SQL query that simply returns all the values of the table (I.E. SELECT * from t;)

My question is: This seems to me rather inefficient and wasteful. Everytime I add (or remove) a task, I should run another query that goes over all the values in the table, and returns a cursor to them. 
I wonder if there's another, more efficient, way to do this.

I should note that I'm very new to android programming, so I would appriciate any advice and corrections.

Thanks!